# Implementing server-side caching middleware in tRPC 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, trpc

I'm working on a Next.js project and looking to implement in-memory caching for tRPC results, with each tRPC procedure being able to opt-in with a custom TTL. I think tRPC's middleware would be suitable for this purpose. Unfortunately, the [current tRPC middleware documentation](https://trpc.io/docs/server/middlewares) doesn't seem to cover this specific scenario.

How can a server-side caching middleware in tRPC 10 be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a related discussion on a [Github issue](https://github.com/trpc/trpc/issues/4066) for a feature request that allows to do this easily. In the meanwhile, it is still possible to do this by implementing custom logic.

The example below uses `node-cache` as an in-memory caching approach. It's been tested with tRPC 10.43.3. Procedures listed in `cachedProcedures` are configured to opt into the cache.

```js
// src/app/api/middleware/cache.ts

import { initTRPC } from "@trpc/server";
import NodeCache from "node-cache";

const cacheSingleton = new NodeCache();

// A map of cached procedure names to a callable that gives a TTL in seconds
const cachedProcedures: Map<string, (() => number) | undefined> = new Map();
cachedProcedures.set("router0.procedure0", () => 2 * 3600); // 2 hours
cachedProcedures.set("router0.procedure1", () => 1800); // 30 minutes
cachedProcedures.set("router1.procedure0", secondsUntilMidnight); // dynamic TTL
cachedProcedures.set("router1.procedure1", () => undefined); // never expires

const t = initTRPC.create();
const middlewareMarker = "middlewareMarker" as "middlewareMarker" & {
  __brand: "middlewareMarker";
};


const cacheMiddleware = t.middleware(
  async ({ ctx, next, path, type, rawInput }) => {
    if (type !== "query" || !cachedProcedures.has(path)) {
      return next();
    }
    let key = path;
    if (rawInput) {
      key += JSON.stringify(rawInput).replace(/\"/g, "'");
    }
    const cachedData = cacheSingleton.get(key);
    if (cachedData) {
      return {
        ok: true,
        data: cachedData,
        ctx,
        marker: middlewareMarker,
      };
    }
    const result = await next();

    //@ts-ignore
    // data is not defined in the type MiddlewareResult
    const dataCopy = structuredClone(result.data);

    const ttlSecondsCallable = cachedProcedures.get(path);
    if (ttlSecondsCallable) {
      cacheSingleton.set(key, dataCopy, ttlSecondsCallable());
    } else {
      cacheSingleton.set(key, dataCopy);
    }
    return result;
  }
);
export default cacheMiddleware;
```

```
// src/server/api, or wherever you define tRPC procedures

import cacheMiddleware from "@/app/api/middleware/cache";
...
export const publicProcedure = t.procedure.use(cacheMiddleware);
```

A few remarks:

- The example assumes Next.js app router, but should also work with the pages router or any other framework
- The cache is only enabled for `query` types, not `mutation` or `subscription`
- It uses different cache keys based on the inputs provided to the procedure
- The `middlewareMarker` is a somewhat hacky fix, as any middleware return must include a `marker`
- `structuredClone` is only available in Node 17+, if this is not an option a different deep cloning approach is required
- It would be wise to add logging